# Pregex is not matching the correct pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

When I tried to match a string with regex it is not working. However I think the regex rule is fine with my knowledge. Could anyone please help me to identify what is missing in my expression.

SAMPLE TO MATCH

1. HAD-ORAAS0001545-ORBTD0003457
2. HAD-ORBTD0001545-ORAAS0003457

```
<?php
print_r((preg_match('/^HAD-OR[AAS,BTD][0-9]{5,7}$/','HAD-ORBTD0009999',$m)));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts could you please do add samples also which you want to match etc in your question that will give better understanding of question

Comment: `[AAS,BTD]` -> `(?:AAS|BTD)`, anything inside `[]` only matches one character

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Added the samples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Online regex demo: [Online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WvAuHF/1)

```
^HAD(?:-OR(?:AAS|BTD)[0-9]{5,7}){1,2}$
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^HAD                     ##Checking if it starts with HAD.
(?:                      ##Starting non capturing group from here.
-OR                      ##Matching -OR string here.
(?:                      ##Starting a non-capturing group here.
AAS|BTD                  ##Matching either AAS OR BTD here.
)                        ##Closing non-capturing group here.
[0-9]{5,7}               ##Putting digits should come with occurrences of 5 to 7 here.
)                        ##Closing very first non capturing group here.
{1,2}$                   ##Mentioning that either it should be 1 or 2 occurrences of whole first non capturing group.
```